# Simple Employee program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I have created a simple Employee program and I am looking for a code review.

I want to make sure my use of concepts such as double-underscore methods and `@property` annotations are correct. I am also looking for feedback on my methodology.

Please feel free to be critical of each aspect of the program:

```
import time;

#Handles creating and maintaining employees.
class Employee:
  num_of_emps = 0
  raise_amount = 1

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.id = id
    self.pay = pay
    self.manager = None
    self.start_time = time.strftime("%D @ %I:%M:%S %p")
    Employee.num_of_emps += 1
    Employee.raise_amount += .01

  #Method defines a string used
  #to recreate Employee object.
  def __repr__(self):
    return "Employee('{}', '{}', '{}')".format(self.first, self.last, self.pay)

  #Method created for readability
  #for end user.
  def __str__(self):
    return self.info

  #Alternative constructor, built to create
  #Employee objects from strings.
  @classmethod
  def from_string(cls, emp_str):
    first, last, id, pay = emp_str.split('-')
    return cls(first, last, id, pay)

  #Method built to check if a
  #date falls on the weekend.
  @staticmethod
  def is_workday(day):
    if day.weekday() == 5 or day.weekday() == 6:
      return False
    return True

  #Method developed s/t supervisor's employees
  #will always also be managers employees.
  def set_manager(self, mgr):
    self.manager = mgr

  #Method prints employee information.
  @property
  def info(self):
    if isinstance(self, Manager):
      return print("Manager's ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.fullname, "\nSalary:", self.pay,
                   "\nEmployee's under supervision:", self.print_emp, "\nEmployee stated on:", self.start_time)
    if isinstance(self, Supervisor):
      return print("Supervisor's ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.fullname, "\nSalary:", self.pay,
                   "\nEmployee's under supervision:", self.print_emp, "\nEmployee stated on:", self.start_time)
    elif isinstance(self, Developer):
      return print("Developer's ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.fullname, "\nSalary:", self.pay,
                   "\nPrograming Language:", self.prog_laung, "\nEmployee stated on:", self.start_time)
    else:
      return print("Employee ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.fullname, "\nSalary:", self.pay,
                   "\nEmployee stated on:", self.start_time)

  #Given an Employee object one can change
  #its pay amount.
  @property
  def new_raise(self):
    self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount)

  #The following three methods created to manage
  #Employee objects full name.
  @property
  def fullname(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

  @fullname.setter
  def fullname(self, name):
    first, last = name.split(' ')
    self.first = first
    self.last = last

  @fullname.deleter
  def fullname(self):
    self.fisrt = None
    self.last = None
    print('Name has been deleted.')


#Manager class, inherits from Employee class.
class Manager(Employee):
  raise_amount = 1.04

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup = None):
    super().__init__(first, last, id, pay)
    if emp_under_sup is None:
      self.emp_under_sup = []
    else:
      self.emp_under_sup = emp_under_sup

  #Alternative constructor, built to create
  #Employee objects from strings.
  @classmethod
  def from_string(cls, emp_str):
    first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup = emp_str.split('-')
    return cls(first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup=None)

  #Add an Employee object to the managers
  #employee supervision list.
  def add_emp(self, emp):
    if emp not in self.emp_under_sup:
      self.emp_under_sup.append(emp)
      emp.set_manager(self)

  #Remove an Employee object from the managers
  #employee supervision list.
  def remove_emp1(self, emp):
    if emp in self.emp_under_sup:
      self.emp_under_sup.remove(emp)

  @property
  def print_emp(self):
    return ', '.join([emp.fullname for emp in self.emp_under_sup])


#Supervisor class, inherits from Employee class.
class Supervisor(Employee):
  raise_amount = 1.03

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup = None):
    super().__init__(first, last, id, pay)
    if emp_under_sup is None:
      self.emp_under_sup = []
    else:
      self.emp_under_sup = emp_under_sup

  #Alternative constructor, built to create
  #Employee objects from strings.
  @classmethod
  def from_string(cls, emp_str):
    first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup = emp_str.split('-')
    return cls(first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup=None)

  #Add an Employee object to the supervisors
  #employee supervision list.
  def add_emp(self, emp):
    if emp not in self.emp_under_sup:
      self.emp_under_sup.append(emp)
      if self.manager:
        self.manager.add_emp(emp)

  #Remove an Employee object from the supervisors
  #employee supervision list.
  def remove_emp(self, emp):
    if emp in self.emp_under_sup:
      self.emp_under_sup.remove(emp)

  @property
  def print_emp(self):
    return ', '.join([emp.fullname for emp in self.emp_under_sup])


#Developer class, inherits from Employee class.
class Developer(Employee):
  raise_amount = 1.02

  def __init__(self, first, last, id, pay, prog_laung):
    super().__init__(first, last, id, pay)
    self.prog_laung = prog_laung

  #Alternative constructor, built to create
  #Employee objects from strings.
  @classmethod
  def from_string(cls, emp_str):
    first, last, id, pay, prog_laung = emp_str.split('-')
    return cls(first, last, id, pay, prog_laung)
```

Comment: How would this be used? What problem does it solve?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question instead.

Answer (score 3):

As a warning, I'm rather nit-picky, but here's everything I see:

- Run your code through flake8 to ensure PEP8 compliance
- Some of your names are a bit under-specified. I'd prefer `first_name` and `last_name` to `first` and `last` (first and last what?). Also, as a general rule, [names are hard](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and it's actually not safe to assume a person has a first and last name. I'd rename `pay` to `salary`. Instead of `emp_under_sup` how about `supervisees` or `direct_reports`? Similarly, instead of `add_emp` how about `add_supervisee`? `prog_laung` should probably be `programming_language`.

  - Your ordering of `first, last, id` is a little strange. Usually the id comes first.
  - Generally we use `"""Doc comments."""` to document method and classes instead of `# inline comments`
  - Good use of `@classmethod` in your `from_string` methods
  - It seems from `raise_amount` that you use floats for money. [**Never use floats for money!**](https://www.noelherrick.com/blog/always-use-decimal-for-money)
  - You use a list comprehension in many instances where a generator comprehension would be just fine (and doesn't build the intermediate list up in memory). Ex instead of `return ', '.join([emp.fullname for emp in self.emp_under_sup])` try `return ', '.join(emp.fullname for emp in self.emp_under_sup)`
  - In Python we tend to try things and catch failures instead of asking for permission beforehand. So for example instead of:

```
if emp in self.emp_under_sup:
    self.emp_under_sup.remove(emp)
```

Try:

```
try:
    self.emp_under_sup(remove)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

You may also want to revisit why you are suppressing this. Shouldn't it be an error if you try to remove a supervisee that isn't supervised by that employee?

- In `return cls(first, last, id, pay, emp_under_sup=None)` there is no need to provide `emp_under_sup=None` as it defaults to `None`.
- Prefer ternaries when possible, ex: `self._emp_under_sup = [] if emp_under_sup is None else emp_under_sup`
- `print('Name has been deleted.')` is a bad idea for code that you want others to use. What if someone wants to use your code in a place where they don't want that printed?
- Why do you have a deleter on `fullname`? What does "deleting" someone's name even mean? You probably don't need it.
- `name.split(' ')` may return more than 2 parts (which will cause your tuple unpacking to `ValueError`). Instead try `name.split(' ', 1)` to limit to 1 split by space.
- If you're using Python >=3.6 use f-strings instead of format strings. Ex. `return f'{self.first} {self.last}'` instead of `return "{} {}".format(self.first, self.last)` (we also prefer double quotes for format strings on Python <= 3.5)
- Your use of `@property` and the setter for `fullname` is good (although I'd call it `full_name`. But all of your other properties are misused. Properties that aren't settings almost never should mutate things (because it's unexpected). See `new_raise`. Instead try something like `employee.give_raise()`, which more explicitly indicates that `employee` will be mutated. `info` and `print_emp` also shouldn't be properties (the fact that `print_emp` has a verb in its name is a good indicator). Look into maybe overriding `__str__` for this purpose.
- Consider maybe having `manager` be a property instead of having a `set_manager()`. Then the setter for it can ensure that the employee is added to the manager's `emp_under_sup` list.
- You have duplicate behavior for managers and supervisors. Are they the same? If not, consider multiple inheritance or having `Manager` inherit the supervisee list and methods from `Supervisor`
- `is_workday()` doesn't make sense as a classmethod on Employee. This should probably be on its own.
- `import time;` should be `import time`
- Setting `self.start_time = time.strftime("%D @ %I:%M:%S %p")` in the constructor is rather inflexible and doesn't allow for a different start time (say if you load the employee from a file that started a few years ago). Instead try taking `start_time` as a parameter to the constructor. Then perhaps add a `@classmethod` called `create`, which accepts `first, last, id, pay` but passes `time.strftime("%D @ %I:%M:%S %p")` as the `start_time` into the constructor.
- Your use of class variables seems glitchy and feels like it doesn't what you wanted. Avoid these where possible.
- Your serialization straight up doesn't work. It doesn't indicate the object type that it has printed out, so you can't tell from a string whether it was an Employee or a Manager that was serialized. Instead of trying to do this yourself, why not use a builtin solution like [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). From this, it's pretty clear you haven't tested this code. Because this just won't work. **Test your code!**
- Your `repr` can't be "used to recreate Employee object." It gives 3 arguments but the `Employee` constructor takes 4 (and the last 2 are presumably not strings). Try: `return f'Employee({repr(self.first)}, {repr(self.last)}, {repr(self.id)}, {repr(self.pay)})'`
- Why store the `start_time` as a string. Use `datetime.datetime.now()` to give you `datetime` object which allows you to do math and interrogate (ex. you can compute how many years the employee has been with the company with `datetime.datetime.now() - start_time`)

With all of this, I'd try reformatting your code like so:

```
import datetime


class Employee:
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, id, first_name, last_name, salary):
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        return cls(id, first_name, last_name, salary, start_time)

    def __init__(self, id, first_name, last_name, salary, start_time):
        self.id = id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.salary = salary

        self._manager = None

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

    def give_raise(self, amount):
        self.salary += amount

    @property
    def manager(self):
        return self._manager

    @manager.setter
    def manager(self, manager):
        # The manager sets self._manager for us
        manager.add_direct_report(self)

    @manager.deleter
    def manager(self):
        # The manager None's self._manager for us
        self._manager.remove_direct_report(self)


class Manager(Employee):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, id, first_name, last_name, salary, direct_reports=None):
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        return cls(id, first_name, last_name, salary, start_time,
                   direct_reports)

    def __init__(self, id, first_name, last_name, salary, start_time,
                 direct_reports=None):
        super().__init__(id, first_name, last_name, salary, start_time)
        self.direct_reports = [] if direct_reports is None else direct_reports

    def add_direct_report(self, employee):
        self.direct_reports.append(employee)
        employee._manager = self

    def remove_direct_report(self):
        self.direct_reports.remove(employee)
        employee._manager = None


class Developer(Employee):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, id, first_name, last_name, salary, programming_language):
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        return cls(id, first_name, last_name, salary, start_time,
                   programming_language)

    def __init__(self, id, first_name, last_name, salary, start_time,
                 programming_langauge):
        super().__init__(id, first_name, last_name, salary, start_time)
        self.programming_lanague = programming_language
```

It's up to you to properly document this and take another stab at some of the things I excluded (like your borked `raise_amount` logic and global employee counter).

Comment: I am working to understand everything you suggested. Thanks, btw for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: I was confused about the 'property' tag. For instance, I never meant for raise_amount to be changeable but fixed; variable, for each type of employee but unchangeable. Unfortunately, where I work we have a coding standard that sets all indentations to two spaces so I can't write code that is completely PEP8 compliant. I will post my edited version of the program based on your suggestions. I am not sure I hit on all the points you made so if you wouldn't mind taking another look that would be great!

Comment: With flake8 you can disable specific rules (so `flake8 --ignore=E111` will suppress errors about your 2-space tabs). Whether you wanted `raise_amount` to be changeable `new_raise` definitely should not have been a `@property` (and I'd give it a better name like `give_raise`). The reason why I removed the `raise_amount` class variable is it didn't make much sense (both logically and from a coding style perspective). Does adding more developers really increase all of their raises? Even if it does, this seems much better suited for a custom collection...

Comment: Say you made an `EmployeeList` that just wraps a regular `list`. It keeps track of how many employees are in the list and provides a method `give_all_raises()` which calls `give_raise()` on each employee with the proper amount (based on how many employees are in the list).